# Adding variable to path so that a python os.environ works

Tags: python, macos, path

I am trying to add this python [library](https://github.com/fcbg-hnp/NeuroDecode) to my MAC. Once the installation is done, I have to

> Create environment variables:
>
> ```
> NEUROD_ROOT = NeuroDecode path
> NEUROD_DATA = path to the desired data folder 
> NEUROD_SCRIPTS = path to the desired scripts folder
> ```

I edited the file `/etc/paths` with nano:

```
sudo nano /etc/paths
```

And the file now looks like:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/Users/mathieu/Documents/NeuroDecode/scripts
NEUROD_ROOT=/Users/mathieu/Documents/NeuroDecode
NEUROD_DATA=/Users/mathieu/Documents/NeuroDecode/SubjectData
NEUROD_SCRIPTS=/Users/mathieu/Documents/NeuroDecode/SubjectScripts
```

Supposely, the file to start NeuroDecode is nd_gui.cmd. Not ideal for macOS I believe, and this file only includes `start /B pythonw %NEUROD_ROOT%/neurodecode/gui/mainWindow.py`. So I tried to shortcut it by adding an alias in my .zshrc file:

```
function runpy() {
    python "$@"
}
alias neurodecode="runpy '/Users/mathieu/Documents/NeuroDecode/neurodecode/gui/mainWindow.py'"
```

*Note: python is also alias and start  python 3.8.5.*

Sadly, it doesn't work. A `KeyError` is raised when the program tries to do `os.environ['NEUROD_ROOT']`. If I have a look at the elemnent `os.environ._data`, I have (incomplete screenshot):

[image: os.environ]

Any idea what I did wrong and how I could properly set the path variables?

Comment: Have you tried to put `export NEUROD_ROOT=/Users/mathieu/Documents/NeuroDecode` in .zshrc ?

Comment: I think you need to do `export PATH="$PATH:$NEUROD_ROOT:/Users/mathieu/Documents/NeuroDecode"`, otherwise, you lose all the existing paths.

Comment: @Philippe Thank you.. should have copy/paste exactly. It works fine!

Comment: @Philippe Actually your first line works. I do not know the difference between both.